# Daily Data Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the stock price of the same company on a daily basis for the next 30 days using Python. I used indexing of list and `.append()`, the initial value gets replaced as soon as the updated price is added. How can I make a list of the price of the same stock for 30 days?

```
*#Catalyst Pharmaceuticals
#New York Stack Exchange
import requests
import pytz
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import csv
r=requests.get('https://robinhood.com/collections/technology')
html=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
csv_file=open('Catalyst Pharmaceuticals Monthly.csv','a')
csv_writer=csv.writer(csv_file)
price_list = []
dttm = []
def websc():
    
    global price_list
    global dttm
    global a_price
    #i=10
        
    
    for p in soup.find_all('a',{'class':'rh-hyperlink'})[2]:
        a_price = p.text
        dd=datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("GMT"))
        dd=dd.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        price_list.append(a_price)
        dttm.append(dd)
        
       
      
    
    zipped = zip(price_list,dttm)
    d = list(zipped)
    print(d)
    csv_writer.writerows(d)
    csv_file.close()
websc()*
```

Comment: first of all: if you only .append() to a list, the data should never get replaced. second of all why are you tagging this with maching-learning and deep-learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the file in append mode rather than write mode if you don't want to overwrite the file

Comment: The 2nd entry is 5 rows below the first entry.

Comment: Are you appending empty lines into the file?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just loop through some tickers, push everything into a dataframe, and then export that to a CSV?

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import scipy.optimize as sco
import datetime as dt
import math
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
np.random.seed(777)


start = '2020-01-01'
end = '2020-08-27'
#N = 165
#start = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=N)
#end = dt.datetime.today()



tickers = ['AAPL','MSFT','GOOG','SBUX','MCD','NKE']

thelen = len(tickers)

price_data = []
for ticker in tickers:
    try:
        prices = wb.DataReader(ticker, start = start, end = end, data_source='yahoo')[['Adj Close']]
        price_data.append(prices.assign(ticker=ticker)[['ticker', 'Adj Close']])
    except:
        print(ticker)
            
df = pd.concat(price_data)
df.dtypes
df.head()
df.shape


# finally....
df.to_csv('file_name.csv')
```

Try that and post back if you need something else, related to this.